# Why these two events triggered repeatedly when they should only run once?

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, repeat

I have written the following code, which is supposed to show a div when moused over another div, the code works but, the events are triggered repeatedly why is this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #my-div {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                background-color: red;
            }
            .tooltip {
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                background-color: red;
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="my-div"></div>
        <div class="tooltip"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('#my-div').on('mouseover', function() {
                        $('.tooltip').fadeIn(300);
                    });
                    $('#my-div').on('mouseleave', function() {
                        $('.tooltip').fadeOut(300);
                    });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/QaJp4/.

Comment: Mouseover and mouseout are triggered when the mouse enters or leave (occordigly) the concerned tag, **or one of it's descendant**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover` because `mouseover` is always trigger when you move mouse in target.

And for more you should added `stop()` to stop the `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` animation trigger as the same time when user move mouse in and out rapidly.

```
$('#my-div').on('mouseenter', function() {
   $('.tooltip').stop().fadeIn(300);
});
$('#my-div').on('mouseleave', function() {
   $('.tooltip').stop().fadeOut(300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out, what is the problem, I use Coda, and it appears to have weird bug, I tried it on all other browsers and it works OK. I wrote this code and it seems to work fine on major browsers, but for some reason Coda refuses to run it correctly:

```
        function Tooltip() {

            this.showToolTip = function() {
                $(this.element).on('mouseenter', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $(that.tooltip).stop().fadeIn(300);
                });
            };

            this.hideToolTip = function() {
                $(this.element).on('mouseleave', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $(that.tooltip).stop().fadeOut(300);
                });
            };

            this.element = arguments[0];
            this.tooltip = arguments[1];
            var that = this;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You expected *mouseout* to behave the same as *mouseleave*.

> ***mouseleave*** and ***mouseout*** are similar but differ in that *mouseleave* does not bubble and *mouseout* does. This means that mouseleave is fired when the pointer has exited the element and all of its descendants, whereas mouseout is fired when the pointer leaves the element or leaves one of the element's descendants (even if the pointer is still within the element). *([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event))*

Nearly the same goes for [***mouseover*** Vs ***mouseenter***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event)

See how often *mouseover* is fired (watch out the counter) as you hover the red container and the text it contains below:

```js
let $p = $('p').eq(0)
    , $tooltip = $('.tooltip').eq(0)
;

$('#target')
  .on('mouseover', () => {
    // Counting fired mouseover events
    $p.text((+$p.text() || 0)+1);
    $tooltip.fadeIn(300);
  })

  .on('mouseleave', () => {
    $tooltip.fadeOut(300);
  });
```

```css
#target {width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: red;}
.tooltip {width: 100px; height: 50px; background-color: red; display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="target"><div>Test</div></div>
<div class="tooltip"></div>
<p></p>
```